# What kind of Freehub body is this?

Tags: cassette, hub, freehub

What kind of Freehub body is this? It looks like an old Uniglide but the threads go all the way down, and it's very short (as I hope you can tell with the ruler).
It's on an unbranded hub attached to a DT Swiss X450 rim.

[image: freehub body]

Comment: What is the other side of the hub like? is it threaded or plain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a singlespeed cassette hub, made for running a singlespeed cassette cog and a stack of spacers to dial chainline, plus its external lockring pictured.